Why is npm library not a function?
There is a problem with npm library for html minify. I downloaded and declared a library
import htmlmin from 'html-minifier'; 

but when i try to run a gulp task
export const html = () => {
  return gulp.src("source/*.html")
    .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
}

but a got an error
TypeError: htmlmin is not a function

I am pretty sure there is no syntax error but I dont know what is a problem.
I tried different liabraries and more old node.js but I still got same problem

Do some basic debugging - if it isn't a function, find out what it is.

it worked after I instaled special library for gulp gulp-htmlmin after a have seen usage for this one
const gulp = require('gulp');
const htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');

gulp.task('minify', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/*.html')
    .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});


Please take a look at library documentation.
There is a precise example of how to use the library with gulp:
const { src, dest, series } = require('gulp');
const htmlMinify = require('html-minifier');

const options = {
  includeAutoGeneratedTags: true,
  removeAttributeQuotes: true,
  removeComments: true,
  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
  removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
  sortClassName: true,
  useShortDoctype: true,
  collapseWhitespace: true
};

function html() {
  return src('app/**/*.html')
    .on('data', function(file) {
      const buferFile = Buffer.from(htmlMinify.minify(file.contents.toString(), options))
      return file.contents = buferFile
    })
    .pipe(dest('build'))
}

exports.html = series(html)


note for OP: this is easily rewritten to use import instead of require - the main point is .minify is the function, which is a property OF the default import/require

how to default import a liabrary? Sorry I am new to javascript
